# Rest api design: POST to create with duplicate data, would-be IntegrityError/500, what would be correct?

Tags: api, http, rest, api-design

I have a normal, basic REST api like:

```
/
    GET - list
    POST - create

/<id>
    GET - detail
    PUT - replace
    PATCH - patch
    DELETE - delete
```

When a POST comes in to `/`, I usually create an object and make a new id. Some (one) of the fields are (is) required to be unique. So, a POST with such duplicate data could result in:

1. 500 - IntegrityError
2. Make it more like a `PUT`/`PATCH` to `/<id>` and update the existing record
3. Catch/avoid the error and return some sort of `4XX`
4. Something else I'm not thinking of.

`1` seems out: the request is either bad or I can deal with it. What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: I'd go with 409, "Conflict". But I'm not about to assert that it's the "correct" way. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

@StevenFisher is correct. [409 Conflict](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10) is the correct response.

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
>   state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
>   it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and
>   resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>   information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict.
>   Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the
>   user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be
>   possible and is not required.

For instance, a GET on / might tell a client that they can create users as follows

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<users href="/">
    <create href="/" method="post">
        <username type="xs:token" cardinality="required"/>
        <password type="password" cardinality="required"/>
    </create>
    ... other hypermedia controls, like search ...
</users>
```

Following the hypermedia control and trying to create a user with the username "Skylar Saveland" might result in

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
<users href="/">
    <create href="/" method="post">
        <username type="xs:token" cardinality="required" 
                  error="The username 'Skylar Saveland' is already taken. Please select another username"/>
        <password type="password" cardinality="required"/>
    </create>
    ... other hypermedia controls, like search ...
</users>
```

Similarly, trying to create a user without a password might result in

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
<users href="/">
    <create href="/" method="post">
        <username type="xs:token" cardinality="required"/>
        <password type="password" cardinality="required" 
                  error="A password must be specified"/>
    </create>
    ... other hypermedia controls, like search ...
</users>
```

or you might have multiple errors, e.g.,

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
<users href="/">
    <create href="/" method="post">
        <username type="xs:token" cardinality="required"
                  error="The username 'Skylar Saveland' is already taken. Please select another username"/>
        <password type="password" cardinality="required"
                  error="A password must be specified"/>
    </create>
    ... other hypermedia controls, like search ...
</users>
```

NOTE: An appropriate [media type will need to be created](http://www.amundsen.com/blog/archives/1041) to go along with the above, which will explain the structure of the hypermedia controls (including the error attributes on the forms) and define the meaning of the various element names (e.g., users, username, password, etc).

Answer (score 2):

#3 is more appropriate. 5xx errors are when there's something wrong with the server. 4xx errors are when something is wrong with the request. In this case, the request is wrong, so a 4xx is more appropriate. Either a 400 or 409.

Or you can do #2, really depends on the context.

Comment: #2 is not correct. POST without an ID should _not_ be used to update a request.